# Good expression for "Come on." in this specific context?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I'm looking for a good word or phrase for the English phrase, "Come on.". Specifically, in a context where you're looking for something in a hurry, like "Come on, come on...!"

Comment: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say どこなんだよう、どこだ、どこだ畜生、なんで見つからないんだ、こんな時に and so on

Comment: The question asks for a phrase when looking for something.

Comment: @sundowner: thank you, didn't read it right the first time

Comment: ...deleted and fixed.. 
I don't have an answer, but to further clarify: 
a) Are you saying that to a person who knows where whatever you are looking for is?
b) You are not yourself sure if the listener knows where it is? 
c)You know the person has deliberately hidden it so you can''t find it?

Comment: @Tuomo I don't think the question or the answer implies a listener. It's just someone saying things in a panic as they search.

Comment: Thanks, you are right (+ long time no write) + good point. I understand that one talks like that to oneself, but (yes, maybe incorrectly) assumed that the reason for the question was to find a way to better interact, i.e. how to say that to someone else.

Comment: if we assume it was a monologue, the answer from @Enno Shioji should be perfect.